# wxPython append and pop message box inside panel serving like a notification center

Tags: python, wxpython

I would like to make a wxpython program that has a notification center just like the one on windows or mac. Whenever I have a message, the message will show inside the the notification panel, and the user could close that message afterwards.

I have a sample code for illustration as follows:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        topPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        panel1 = wx.Panel(topPanel, -1)
        button1 = wx.Button(panel1, -1, label="generate message")

        self.panel2 = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(
            topPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        self.panel2.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.panel2.SetupScrolling()

        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onAdd)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(panel1,-1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border=10)
        sizer.Add(self.panel2,-1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border=10)

        self.sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        topPanel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.panel2.SetSizer(self.sizer2)

    def onAdd(self, event):
        new_text = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel2, value="New Message")
        self.sizer2.Add(new_text,0,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border=1)
        self.panel2.Layout()
        self.panel2.SetupScrolling()


class MyApp(wx.App):
     def OnInit(self):
         frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'frame')
         frame.Show(True)
         return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

In the above I code, the right panel (i.e. panel2) serves as a notification center that all the messages should shown inside it. On the left panel (i.e. panel1) I have a button to generate message just to mimic the notification behavior. Ideally the message on the right panel should be a message box that you could close (maybe a frame? Or a MessageDialog?)

Any hint or advice is much appreciated, and an example would be the best!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out myself, it was easier than I initially thought.

Here is the code:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        self.number_of_panels = 0

        topPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        panel1 = wx.Panel(topPanel, -1)
        button1 = wx.Button(panel1, -1, label="generate message")

        self.panel2 = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(
            topPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        self.panel2.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.panel2.SetupScrolling()

        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onAdd)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(panel1,0,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border=5)
        sizer.Add(self.panel2,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border=5)

        self.sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        topPanel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.panel2.SetSizer(self.sizer2)

    def onAdd(self, event):
        self.number_of_panels += 1
        panel_label = "Panel %s" %  self.number_of_panels
        panel_name = "panel%s" % self.number_of_panels

        new_panel = wx.Panel(self.panel2, name=panel_name, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)

        self.closeButton = wx.Button(new_panel, label='Close %s' % self.number_of_panels)
        self.closeButton.panel_number = self.number_of_panels

        self.closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

        self.sizer2.Add(new_panel,0,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border=1)
        self.panel2.Layout()
        self.panel2.SetupScrolling()

    def OnClose(self, e):

        if self.panel2.GetChildren():
            e.GetEventObject().GetParent().Destroy()
            self.number_of_panels -= 1
            self.panel2.Layout()  # Reset layout after destroy the panel


class MyApp(wx.App):
     def OnInit(self):
         frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'frame')
         frame.Show(True)
         return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Basically I can destroy the newly created panel. I just need to know which panel it is when I click the close button. This should work very similar to the Notification Center.